# How to implement multiple search filters in php

Tags: php, mysql, search, filter

I m trying to implement filters in php and mysql to search record in database....Filters should be like if among 6 filters only two is selected query will perform "AND" operation for these two and fetch data from database and if three then it will perform "AND" operation for these three filters.....
one way to implement is to check for each filter like.

```php
if (isset($_GET['name'] && isset($_GET['city'])) { 
    // perform AND for these two
} elseif(isset($_GET['name'] && (isset($_GET['age'])) {
    // perform AND for these three
}

// and so on ...
```

But the problem is if i have 6 filters then i have to create 64 combinations for it...
I m thinking  about that is there any alternative solution exists for it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could work, assuming that your `$_GET` keys match columns in your table:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

$filtered_get = array_filter($_GET); // removes empty values from $_GET

if (count($filtered_get)) { // not empty
    $query .= " WHERE";

    $keynames = array_keys($filtered_get); // make array of key names from $filtered_get

    foreach($filtered_get as $key => $value)
    {
       $query .= " $keynames[$key] = '$value'";  // $filtered_get keyname = $filtered_get['keyname'] value
       if (count($filtered_get) > 1 && (count($filtered_get)-1 > $key)) { // more than one search filter, and not the last
          $query .= " AND";
       }
    }
}
$query .= ";"
```

`$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'name' AND city = 'city' AND age = 'age';"`

I think this may work, although this code sample does not include sanitization against SQL injection, so you should probably add something to scrub potentially dangerous input

**Updated**: added `$filtered_get = array_filter($_GET);` to filter out any empty fields from `$_GET` array

**Updated**: I edited the if code condition to remove extra "AND" at the end of query "(count($filtered_get)-1 > $key"

Comment: what if an empty input text value is passed here than what will happen ."AND" won't probably work then

Comment: I added a `array_filter()` function to the `$_GET` array to scrub out any empty fields, which should build the query to include only filters that have been set

Comment: Very useful code ,great job !

Comment: I am using the exact same code. However, it types one last ```AND``` in the ending of SQL. Any solutions?

Comment: For anyone who have the same problem of ```AND``` in the SQL statement in last, do the following:
```
$count = count($parameters);
if (($count > 1) && ($count > $key))
 {
 $count = $count - 1;
 $query .= " AND";
}
```
This resolved my problem. However, the theory of that if statement is correct but why it happens is out of my mind. I am using PHP7.4

Answer (score 0):

```
single if condition to check value is empty or not.for non-empty then mysql query is two between 'AND' operation.
$query = 'select * from info';
$where = ' Where';
$and = 'id = 1';
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){
  $and .= ' AND name="test"';
}
if(!empty($_GET['city'])){
  $and .= ' AND city="test"';
}
$q = $query.''.$where.''.$and;
make like this query is 'select & from info where id=1 AND name="test" AND city="test"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prefix for the form elements, like filter-, so items will look like filter-age, filter-name and so on. Now, let's suppose you have a function like

```
function buildFilters($input, $delimiter) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $filters = array();
        $filters[]="1=1";//default filter
        if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) {
            //add the filter to $filters via $filters[]=yourvalue
        }
    }
    return implode($delimiter, $filters);
}
```

and then you can call it like

```
$myFilters = buildFilters($_POST, " AND ");
```

Comment: @Inam I converted your logic into a cycle and separated it into a function. To give you more information I would need to know more about the form you have.

Comment: my form is something like this ...
<form action="filterpage.php"  method = "GET">
<input type="text" name="title"/>
<select name="category[ ]" multiple>
<option value="cat1">cat1</option>
<option value="cat2">cat2</option>
</select>
</form>

Comment: @Inam you could change your form so name = "filter-title" and so on to make it compatible with the code I have given you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the answer from @tshimkus. Maybe it's the way I have the arrays set up or something but there were a couple problems I ran into before getting it to work.

this line:

```
$query .= " $keynames[$key] = '$value'";
```

for me needed to be:

```
$query .= " $key = '$value'";
```

I also didn't get the check (shown below) for last item to work.

```
if (count($filtered_get) > 1 && (count($filtered_get) > $key)) { // more than one search filter, and not the last
```

ended up using a count along with this instead:

```
if($i!==$len){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$whereClause = '  ';
  
    if ( !empty($_POST['gender']) || !empty($_POST['hobby']) || !empty($_POST['search_filter']) ) {
    
    $whereClause .= ' WHERE ';
    if ( !empty($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['hobby']) && !empty($_POST['search_filter']) ) {
        $whereClause .= ' gender = "'.$_POST['gender'].'" AND gender = "'.$_POST['gender'].'" AND search_filter LIKE "%'.$_POST['search_filter'].'%" ';

    } else {

        if ( !empty($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] != "" && empty($_POST['hobby']) && empty($_POST['search_filter']) ) {
            $whereClause .= ' gender = "'.$_POST['gender'].'"  ';          
        }
        else if ( (!empty($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] != "") &&  (!empty($_POST['hobby']) || !empty($_POST['search_filter']))) {
            $whereClause .= ' gender = "'.$_POST['gender'].'"  '; 
            $whereClause .= ' AND ';
        }
        
        if ( !empty($_POST['hobby']) && $_POST['hobby'] != "" && empty($_POST['gender']) && empty($_POST['name'])){
            $whereClause .= ' hobby = "'.$_POST['hobby'].'"  ';           
        }
        else if ( (!empty($_POST['hobby']) && $_POST['hobby'] != "") &&  (!empty($_POST['gender']) || !empty($_POST['search_filter']))) {
            $whereClause .= ' hobby = "'.$_POST['hobby'].'"  '; 
            $whereClause .= ' AND ';
        } 
        
        if ( !empty($_POST['search_filter'])) {
            $whereClause .= ' search_filter LIKE "%'.$_POST['search_filter'].'%"  ';       
        }    
    }

}
```